# Django 1.11 - How do I query a DateTimeRangeField with an upper bound of None (PostgreSQL)

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have the following model:

```
class foo(models.Model):
    range = DateTimeRangeField()
```

I want to find all rows where range is unbounded above. I tried the following query:

```
foo.objects.filter(range__endswith = None)
```

but it's giving my this exception: ValueError: Cannot use None as a query value.
How can I do this?

Comment: It [looks like](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2ba588e7736e28626e34fd1b691fd4d5ae6a2cae/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L1119) the lookup was never updated to allow `None` as a value, even though it makes perfect sense with a range field. File a [bug report](https://code.djangoproject.com/)?

Comment: As a workaround, you could probably do a contains query for `datetime.datetime.max`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
foo.objects.filter(range__endswith__isnull = True)
```